# undefined props best practices

Tags: reactjs

Let us assume that there is a `Child` component that is being rendered in this way

```
<Child text="foo" action={this.bar} />
```

Here `text` and `action` are two props given to Child component.

But in the case if there are no props supplied to the `Child` component

```
<Child />
```

the `Child` component would raise an `undefined` props exception `this.props.text is undefined` or something of that sort.

What would be  a best practice to render the `Child` component even when there are no props supplied to it ?

Do I have to always check like so in the `Child` component.

```
if (this.props.text !== undefined) && (this.props.action !== undefined) 
  //then render
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to use `PropTypes` package, for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Person extends Component {
  render () {
    <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
  }
}

Person.propTyeps = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

This will show you a warning message in the console.

In order to use it you need to install it:

```
$ npm install --save prop-types
```

You can find more documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html), hope it helps.